# Is $(rev:r) in Azure DevOps the same across a build pipeline or project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If I have 2 build pipelines. Does the $(rev:r) variable scope and auto increment per separate build pipeline or across the entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each build pipeline.When this build triggers for the first time, the version number will be *.*.1. And the next time *.*.2, then *.*.3 and so on.

`$(Rev:r)` is used to ensure that **every completed build pipeline has a unique name**. So when a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one.

You can also check in this link for other more details:
https://kasunkodagoda.com/2019/04/03/hidden-gems-in-azure-pipelines-creating-your-own-rev-variable-using-counter-expression-in-azure-pipelines/

Answer (score 0):

It would increase for each build individually:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml